# Find all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$ such that: $2^x+17=y^2$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
>   $2^x+17=y^2$.

Its easy to find that $x=6$ is the only even value for $x$, the others have to be odd.
One more thing is that we get $y^2 \equiv 19 \pmod p$, for every prime factor of $x$. But I have no ides what next to do.

Comment: Just a little useless remark: This is an equation "of Ramanujan-Nagell type": there are some interesting properties of this kind of equations on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation; but it really doesn't help your specific problem :-)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/887651/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles It is a solution to the problem, but I think there shouldnt be a more elementar way to do it.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Why are you claiming that $2^x\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ for every prime factor $p$ of $x$?

Comment: $x=3,5,6,9$ by bruteness .   The powers  of two have a last digit sequence of 2,4,8,6 repeating, producing a last digit sequence of 9, 1, 5, and 3, when added with 17, thus since no square ends in three we can rule out all $x \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.