# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $2^8+2^{12}+2^n$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Find all positive integers $n$ such that $2^8+2^{12}+2^n$ is a perfect square.

For $n=2$ and $n=11$, $2^8+2^{12}+2^n$ is a perfect square.

How to find a closed form?

Comment: Another one is $n=13$.

Comment: For $n\ge 8$, we reduce the problem to deciding when $1+2^4+2^{n-8}=17+2^{n-8}$ is square.

Comment: The odd is the main part of this problem. Modular bashing for larger values maybe?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Solve $2x^2+17=y^2$, and take these $x_k=2^m \mod p$

Comment: That's a Pell equation so that will have infinitely many solutions...

Comment: @Michael How did you get the equation $2x^2+17=y^2$?

Comment: $2^8+2^{12}+2^{2m+1}=256(17+2(2^{m-4})^2)=(16y)^2$

Comment: @display_error What is the source of this problem?

Comment: The only solutions for n<1000 seem to be 2, 11, 13, 14, 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\in\{1,2,\ldots,7\}$, then $n=2$ is the only solution. Let $n\ge 8$. Then $2^8\left(1+2^4+2^{n-8}\right)$ is a square iff $17+2^{n-8}$ is a square. Let $n-8=m$. You're solving $17+2^m=k^2$ in non-negative integers.

All the solutions are $m=3,5,6,9$. Now, the solutions for $m$ are relatively large, and assuming $m\ge 10$ and using mod $2^{k}$, $k\ge 10$ won't help, because $17$ will always be a quadratic residue.

This is very similar to [Ramanujan–Nagell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation), namely $2^n-7=x^2$, which has the solutions $n=3,4,5,7,15$.

This equation has already been asked about on M.SE (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426987/find-all-x-y-in-mathbbn-such-that-2x17-y2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887651/exponential-diophantine-23x17-y2)), and the only solution someone could come up with uses Mordell's equations, so I'll use them here. We have three cases:

- $m=3t,\, t\ge 0$. Then $17+\left(2^t\right)^3=k^2$. But $17+a^3=b^2$ has $16$ solutions (see http://oeis.org/A081119 and http://oeis.org/A081119/b081119.txt), which can be found with a program or [this table](http://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/mordell.html#tbl5):

  $$(a,b)=(-2,\pm 3), (-1,\pm 4), (2,\pm 5), (4,\pm 9),$$

  $$ (8,\pm 23), (43,\pm 282), (52,\pm 375),
      (5234,\pm 378661)$$
  This gives $m=3,6,9$.
- $m=3t+1,\, t\ge 0$. Then $2^m\equiv 2\pmod{7}$, so $k^2\equiv 5\pmod{7}$, impossible, because $5$ is not a quadratic residue mod $7$.
- $m=3t+2,\, t\ge 0$. Then $272+\left(2^{t+2}\right)^3=(4k)^2$. But $272+a^3=b^2$ has $2$ solutions (http://oeis.org/A081119/b081119.txt), which are $(a,b)=(8,\pm 28)$. This gives $m=5$.